# Fetching from txtfield and connecting to the database as well as nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is in My EJS file Where it says that Message is not declared.
I want the Thing written in the textfield to produce key search in the JS file TO carry further operations.

```
<script> 
                        $(document).ready(function ajx() 
                        {
                            $("input").on("keydown",function (e) 
                            {
                                if(e.keyCode == 13)
                                {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    message = document.getElementById("typing").value;
                                    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
                                    iDiv.id = 'chatContent';
                                    $("span")[0].appendChild(iDiv).innerHTML=message;
                                    this.value="";
                                    var data = {username:'user101'};
                                    console.log(data);

                                    $.ajax(
                                        {
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            data: JSON.stringify(data),
                                            url: 'http://localhost:8800/',
                                            success: function(data) 
                                            {
                                                console.log('success');
                                                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                                                document.getElementById('chatContent').innerHTML= "<%=message%>"
                                            }
                                        });
                                }
                            })
                            $("input").on("focus",function(e)
                            {
                                document.getElementById("chat-feedback").innerHTML="<p><i>Typing....</i></p>"
                            });
                            $("input").on("blur",function(e)
                            {
                                document.getElementById("chat-feedback").innerHTML="<p id='ignore'>........</p> ";
                            });
                        });
                    </script> 
                <!-- </form> -->

            </div>   <!-- end chat -->
            <input type="text" id="typing" onkeydown="ajx()">
```

Here is the JS file where i have used the Message variable to post the thing..If i remove the ajax type:post then i will print last row of my db not the whole db with the key search of what entered in text field in the above code.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url ="mongodb://localhost:27017/Chatbot_Project";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) 
{
    if (err) throw err;
    db = client.db("Chatbot_Project");
    var data = db.collection('Question').find();
data.forEach(function (results, err)
{
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    var string = JSON.stringify(results);
    console.log(string);
}); 
});

module.exports = function (app)
{

    app.get('/' , function(req,res)
    {
    res.render('index');
})

app.post('/' , function (req , res)
{
    const searchTerm = req.body.message;
    db.find({$text:{$search : searchTerm }},{projection:{_id: 0, What_are_those:1}}).exec((err,str_ID) =>
    {
        res.send('index',{message:str_ID}); 
    })
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think changing 'message =' to 'var message =' will get rid of the error. You are currently setting it as a global variable, identical to 'window.message =', this is not allowed implicitly in module files and is generally considered bad practise.

Comment: nope there is no issue for that thing... It is something else